# VB stretch DataGridViewImageColumn images programmatically

Tags: vb.net, image, datagridview

## What I am doing

I am developing a VisualBasic application where the GUI is separated from the data manipulation (frontend and backend). This particular piece of code keeps track of the Serial Numbers already measured and displays them in the Form as a DGV with the serial number and an image or not.

## My code

In a class that the GUI Form instantiates, my data is stored in a DataTable with a BindingSource, with the second column displaying an Image when I tell it to in the program (Nothing in the beginning):

```vb
Public SerialNumbersBindingSource As New BindingSource
Public SerialNumbersDataTable As New DataTable
(...)
SerialNumbersBindingSource.DataSource = SerialNumbersDataTable
SerialNumbersDataTable.Columns.Add("Serial", Type.GetType("System.String"))
SerialNumbersDataTable.Columns.Add("Pass", MyImage.GetType)
```

In my GUI Form code, a DataGridView has its DataSource set to the former DataTable:

```vb
DataGridViewSerialNumber.DataSource = MyObject.SerialNumbersDataTable
```

By just updating the DataTable in my class, the DataGridView updates automatically to reflect the current state of it. I do it like:

```vb
SerialNumbersDataTable.Add(CurrentSerial, MyImage)
```

## The results I get

The code works, so I can modify and access the DataTable and the DataGridView autoupdates. But the images are not stretching, so I can only see a small part of them.

## What I need

I need the second column named "Pass" in DataGridView to stretch the images.

## What have I tried

If I access the column, it is treated like a DGVColumn and not a DGVImageColumn, so the Layout operation fails.

```vb
DataGridViewSerialNumber.Columns("Pass").DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch
```

Microsoft's Docs page tells me to do this, which treats the columns like DGVImageColumn as I need "Pass" to. It fails because the first column is a Text one, not image.

```vb
For Each column As DataGridViewImageColumn In DataGridViewSerialNumber.Columns("Pass")
    column.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch
Next
```

Also I have tried creating a local DGVImageColumn, modify it and write it onto the original column, but it is read-only.

```vb
Dim imageColumn As DataGridViewImageColumn
imageColumn = DataGridViewSerialNumber.Columns("Pass")
imageColumn.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch
DataGridViewSerialNumber.Columns("Pass") = imageColumn
```

I have also tried to do it from the designer. If I click the DGV, arrow to the right and 'Edit Column', I can create the two columns and setup Pass as ImageColumn with Stretched Layout. But when I set up DGVSerialNumbers.Datasource to my DataTable, it adds the DataTable's columns to the DGV's.

[Failed DGV with columns added in designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQS0A.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's time for you to learn how to cast. If you want to access one column then don't use a loop.  Simply access the column you want and then cast it as the type you want to use it as.  You also need to actually assign the appropriate value to the appropriate property.

```
DirectCast(DataGridViewSerialNumber.Columns("Pass"), DataGridViewImageColumn).ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch
```

If you want to break that up for clarity:

```
Dim imageColumn = DirectCast(DataGridViewSerialNumber.Columns("Pass"), DataGridViewImageColumn)

imageColumn.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch
```

Also, be aware that `Stretch` will not retain the original aspect ratio, so you might want to use `Zoom` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! Casting worked perfectly, today I learned something new from you :)